# Local or remote database with react-native?

Tags: android, reactjs, database, react-native

I'm creating an app for Android and would like to publish it in the play store. Now I should connect the database to my application but I have a lot of problems with firebase. What other databases can I use with react-native? Local or remote? Thanks for the replies

Comment: You can use separate backend application with any database